# Как сделать чтобы bacground обтекал изображение?

Tags: html, css, веб-программирование

Хочу чтобы background не заезжал под изображение, а обтекал его как и текст. Возможно ли это сделать? Пробовал margin и max-width, но при других разрешениях текст уезжает вниз и ввыглядит некорректно.
[image]

```css
.photo {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 10px;
}

.photo_text {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-style: italic;
    font-size: 80%;
    text-align: center;
}

.block_hiden {
    background-color: #EEEEFF;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
    <script src='valaam.js'></script>
    <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='valaam.css'>
    <title>Работа:</title>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Остров Валаам
        <a><img src='images/valaam_gray.gif'></a>
    </h1>

    <div class='photo'>
        <img src='images/valaam.jpg'>
        <p class='photo_text'>&laquo;Фото А. Колыбалова (<a href='www.rg.ru'>www.rg.ru</a>)&raquo;</p>
    </div>

    <div>
        <p>Валаам&nbsp;&mdash; остров в северной части Ладожского озера, самый большой в составе Валаамского архипелага. На острове расположен посёлок Валаам, входящий в Сортавальское городское поселение, и Валаамский ставропигиальный мужской монастырь,
            являющийся памятником русского зодчества. Название острова, возможно, происходит от финно&nbsp;&mdash; угорского слова &laquo;валамо&raquo;&nbsp;&mdash; высокая (горная) земля.</p>

        <p>Остров неоднократно посещали императоры Александр I и Александр II, другие члены императорской фамилии. Также приезжал на Валаам святитель Игнатий (Брянчанинов). Природа Валаама вдохновляла известнейших гениев творчества и науки.</p>
    </div>

    <div id="block" class="block_hiden">
        <p>Здесь побывали художники И.И. Шишкин, Ф.А. Васильев, А.И. Куинджи, писатели и поэты Н.С. Лесков, Ф.И. Тютчев, А.Н. Апухтин, И.С. Шмелёв, Б.К. Зайцев, композиторы П.И. Чайковский, А.К. Глазунов, учёные М.Н. Миклухо-Маклай, Д.И. Менделеев и множество
            других. В XIX веке во время своего путешествия по России остров посетил Александр Дюма-отец.</p>

        <p>Хорошо известны валаамские пейзажи, написанные И.И. Шишкиным (&laquo;Вид Валаама&raquo;, 1860), А.И. Куинджи (&laquo;На острове Валаам&raquo;, 1873) и Николаем Рерихом (&laquo;Святой остров&raquo;, 1917). Ряд современных художников, в частности,
            известный петрозаводский график А.И. Авдышев, в 1970&ndash;х годах создал серию черно&nbsp;&mdash; белых линогравюр. Приезжал на Валаам и посвящал ему свои работы мастер объёмной резьбы по дереву, сортавальский художник Кронид Гоголев.</p>
    </div>

    <p>Назовите ближайший город, из которого можно приехать на о. Валаам:</p>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

> Хочу чтобы background не заезжал под изображение, а обтекал его как и текст. Возможно ли это сделать?

Нет. Фон так не умеет.

Честно говоря, так себе эффект.

Но в вашем случае можно симулировать такое поведение, например, таким костылем (комментарии в коде):

```css
.photo {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 10px;
  background: white;  /* задаем фон, чтоб не просвечивало */
  padding: 0 10px 10px 0;  /* отступы */
  border-right: 1px solid blue;  /* бордеры врезки - такие же как у текста с фоном */
  border-bottom: 1px solid blue;
}

/* абзацы перед текстом с фоном снабжаем псевдоэлементом того же цвета, что и фон врезки - они перекроют ЧАСТЬ его бордера */
.sss p {
  position: relative;
}

.sss p:before {
  content: "";
  border-left: 1px solid #fff;
  height: calc(100% + 1em);
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: -10.9px;
}

/* добавлено чисто для наглядности */
.photo img {
  width: 200px;
  height: 250px;
}

.photo_text {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-style: italic;
  font-size: 80%;
  text-align: center;
}

.block_hiden {
  background-color: #EEEEFF;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class='photo'>
  <img src='images/valaam.jpg'>
  <p class='photo_text'>&laquo;Фото А. Колыбалова (<a href='www.rg.ru'>www.rg.ru</a>)&raquo;</p>
</div>

<div class="sss">
  <p>Валаам&nbsp;&mdash; остров в северной части Ладожского озера, самый большой в составе Валаамского архипелага. На острове расположен посёлок Валаам, входящий в Сортавальское городское поселение, и Валаамский ставропигиальный мужской монастырь, являющийся
    памятником русского зодчества. Название острова, возможно, происходит от финно&nbsp;&mdash; угорского слова &laquo;валамо&raquo;&nbsp;&mdash; высокая (горная) земля.</p>

  <p>Остров неоднократно посещали императоры Александр I и Александр II, другие члены императорской фамилии. Также приезжал на Валаам святитель Игнатий (Брянчанинов). Природа Валаама вдохновляла известнейших гениев творчества и науки.</p>
</div>

<div id="block" class="block_hiden">
  <p>Здесь побывали художники И.И. Шишкин, Ф.А. Васильев, А.И. Куинджи, писатели и поэты Н.С. Лесков, Ф.И. Тютчев, А.Н. Апухтин, И.С. Шмелёв, Б.К. Зайцев, композиторы П.И. Чайковский, А.К. Глазунов, учёные М.Н. Миклухо-Маклай, Д.И. Менделеев и множество
    других. В XIX веке во время своего путешествия по России остров посетил Александр Дюма-отец.</p>

  <p>Хорошо известны валаамские пейзажи, написанные И.И. Шишкиным (&laquo;Вид Валаама&raquo;, 1860), А.И. Куинджи (&laquo;На острове Валаам&raquo;, 1873) и Николаем Рерихом (&laquo;Святой остров&raquo;, 1917). Ряд современных художников, в частности, известный
    петрозаводский график А.И. Авдышев, в 1970&ndash;х годах создал серию черно&nbsp;&mdash; белых линогравюр. Приезжал на Валаам и посвящал ему свои работы мастер объёмной резьбы по дереву, сортавальский художник Кронид Гоголев.</p>
</div>

<p>Назовите ближайший город, из которого можно приехать на о. Валаам:</p>
```

Не пытался делать и проверять с возможными другими эффектами типа теней. Возможно, это решаемо иначе, например, с помошью обрезки clip-path и скриптов.